# Model inheritance in swagger loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

How could I display with loopback in swagger the subclass models?

This is my swagger definition

[image: Swagger definition]

Now it is only displayed the Order and Payload in the swagger, but I'd like to display also the PayloadMessage and PayloadDisbursement. Both models extend the Payload model and could be used in the "order.payload" variable. But only the superclass is displayed in the swagger

This is my PayloadDisbursement

```
{
  "name": "PayloadDisbursement",
  "plural": "PayloadDisbursements",
  "base": "Payload",
  ...
}
```

And this is my PayloadMessage:

```
{
  "name": "PayloadMessage",
  "plural": "PayloadMessages",
  "base": "Payload",
   ...
}
```

Is anything else I should do to show theses model in the swagger?

Comment: To be clear, this is the LoopBack explorer UI, not swagger. As far as I know you can't modify it, but you would not be exposing this publicly anyway, right?

Comment: Why shouldn't I  publish it? I want to expose it to the front-end developers. Not in production but at least in some internal environment.

Comment: It was my impression, and I could be wrong, that the UI was just for local dev only. I could be wrong of course. :)